# "Many a..." in Portuguese

Tags: vocabulário, nomes

In English, there is a particular construction which uses the words "*many a*", and is followed strictly by a singular noun. Here are [some examples](http://hosbeg.com/many-a-how-to-use-many-a-in-a-sentence/):

> - For *many a day* it rained heavily such that we could barely go out.
> - *Many a celebrity* today did not graduate high school.
> - *Many an* English *teacher* speaks very good English.
> - *Many an Englishman* supports Manchester United FC.

This construction is more of a literary construction which can help one add more flavour to their speech. Does a equivalent/similar construction exist in Portuguese, and if so, how is it achieved?

Comment: Qual é que é o efeito que queres? É simplesmente dizer _muitos_ / _muitas_ de forma poética?

Comment: Sim, simplesmente dizer muitos / muitas de forma poética.

Comment: Nos três últimos exemplos, podes dizer _muita celebridade_, _muito professor de inglês_, _muito inglês_ (mas é mais difícil _durante muito dia_). É uma construção mais incomum, mas não particularmente literária.

Comment: @MrChasi Voltaste ao inglês. O teu português já é muito bom (vi na tua pergunta anterior). Quando quiseres perguntar em português, não te inibas. Nós cá estamos para corrigir os teus enganos.

Comment: A sério? Muito obrigado haha. Sim, tens razão, vou escrever uma parte em Português em breve @Jacinto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***My answer is valid regarding Brazillian Portuguese.***

---

You can do this in several ways in Portuguese. The language molds itself to the intention of the speaker, and sometimes the poetic effect is achieved not by the use of this or that word, but by the whole. I'll give some examples.

"Alguma", while normally translated as "some", can have the effect of many when it starts a construction like the ones you propose.

- Many a celebrity today did not graduate high school.
- Alguma celebridade hoje não se graduou no ensino médio.

  > Normally when used this way on the spoken form, *alguma* gets emphasis, being pronounced with the start of the word a bit slower, like "al-guma".

Other option you have is going with "Não são poucos/poucas". This is directly translated to "not a few", and is used to call attention to a quantity that is above average.

- Não são poucas as celebridades que não se graduaram no ensino médio.

  > You have to pay attention to the concordance on this form.

"Tantos/Tantas" can be used to denote a great quantity of anything when used to start a given phrase. It creates a bit of poetical effect, and normally is not seem on spoken form, being more common on literature. Those words should be used when the phrase is connected to something else that gives more context or continue the line of thought somehow.

- Tantas as celebridades que não se graduram no ensino médio, servindo hoje de exemplo para jovens de que o sucesso pode vir fácil quando...

  > "Tantas"/"Tantos" get weird fast if your context doesn't add relevant information to the text.

"Numerosos são "/"Numerosas são" - Functionally equal to "many a". Translates directly to "Numerous are", and is pretty rare on spoken language but relatively common on literature.

- Numerosas são as celebridades que não se graduaram no ensino médio.

Comment: a primeira não percebo. «alguma celebridade» significa «muitas celebridades»?! E «tantos» é poético no Brasil? Mas tirando esses pontos e opções estilísticas que seriam diferentes em Portugal, são boas sugestões.

Comment: @Artefacto Certamente, se usadas no contexto certo! Podes dizer tranquilamente "Alguma cerveja já tomei neste bar" - isto indicaria que já tomaste diversas cerveja no dito local. "Tanto" normalmente é utilizada em construções que exigem contexto para fazerem sentido, mas tem cunho poético: "Tantas as alegrias me deste, meu bem, que me fizeste uma das pessoas mais felizes do mundo".

Comment: @Artefacto O efeito poético de tantos se restringe ao uso no começo de frases, contudo. Quando usadas no corpo de uma oração, o "soco poético" se perde e ela se torna uma torna uma palavra regular.

Comment: 1) tudo bem, mas apenas porque o contexto deixa claro que é um eufemismo, poderias também "umas poucas" ou algo do género, 2) quando ao cunho poético parece-me mais relacionado com a ordem mais incomum das palavras do que qualquer outra coisa, «São tantas as alegrias que me deste!», «Deste-me tantas alegrias» são frases normalíssimas. Poderíamos também jogar com a ordem com «muitas»: «Muitas alegrias me deste tu!»

Comment: @Artefacto Estás correto quanto ao cunho poético ser relacionado a ordem. Ambos os teus exemplos para "São tantas as alegrias que me deste" e "Deste-me tantas alegrias" são _extremamente_ raros no Brasil - a forma mais usada é "Me deste tantas alegrias", bem diferente das que propõe!

Comment: @Artefacto Reforço que minha resposta é válida em um âmbito brasileiro. Estou certo que Portugal tem muitas diferenças em relação ao que é ou não considerado poético, que pode estar causando este desentendimento!

Comment: Esse exemplo do *alguma cerveja* parece melhor que o da celebridade, só com ele consegui entender a intenção. Acho que precisa também da entoação correta para isso ser entendido.

Answer (score 1):

I speak pt-BR.
"many a/an/another" is unusual in English, in the spoken language. It's more often used in literature but I wouldn't say it's poetic. It's been in usage since the thirteenth century and sounds a bit old-fashioned. I see no equivalent to it in pt-BR other than "muitos".  Of course you might say "numerosos" but that's not equivalent to "many a...". "numerosos" means "numerous".

Comment: Com uns exemplos de uso isto ficaria, ó, *muá*, top.